# How does QValidator.fixup() works in PySide?

Tags: python, pyside

I created a QLineEdit and attached a custom QValidator to it. I tried to add a `fixup()` function to my QValidator. When I enter some text in the QLineEdit, it calls `validate()`, then it calls `fixup()`, and finally it calls `validate()` again, but still with the text like it was before the fixup. What did I do wrong? Why isn't the QLineEdit updated by the fixup?

```
mylineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
mylineedit.setValidator(MyValidator())

class MyValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        rx = QtCore.QRegExp('\\d+ m')
        super().__init__(rx, parent)

    def validate(self, text, pos):
        r = super().validate(text, pos)
        print(r)
        return r

    def fixup(self, text):
        if len(text) == 0:
            text = '0 m'
        else:
            text = text.strip() + ' m'
        print(text)
        return text
```

The output would be something like (if I press '1' + Enter):

```
(PySide.QtGui.QValidator.State.Intermediate, '1', 1)
1 m
(PySide.QtGui.QValidator.State.Intermediate, '1', 1)
```

Comment: Look at `void QValidator::fixup ( QString & input ) const`. `input` is a reference and `QString` is mutable. So you should change `text` in `fixup` in place, instead of assign a new string to it.

Comment: In PySide, QString are python strings, and function arguments are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default implementation of **QValidator** in PySide is not good, for the following reasons:

1. the `validate()` method gets called whenever a character is entered or removed, even before the input is complete. This might make editing the field impossible, because all edits towards the target string are invalid and rejected.
2. the `fixup()` method is broken, and it's return value is thrown away.

But there's a workaround. Pass the `QLineEdit` itself to the validator constructor, then you can control when it's validated and fixup it's value if you want:

```
class MyValidator(QValidator):

  def __init__(self, lineedit):
    super(MyValidator, self).__init__()
    self.lineedit = lineedit

  def validate(self, s, p):
    if self.lineedit.hasFocus(): #ignore validation while editing not complete
      return QValidator.Acceptable
    if s.startswith("http://"):
      return QValidator.Acceptable
    return QValidator.Invalid

  def fixup(self, s):
    self.lineedit.setText("http://" + s)
```

Comment: I think this is inaccurate. `validate()` returns one of *three* possible states: 'valid','invalid', and 'intermediate'. The latter ensures that cases like you mention do not happen. From the documentation (http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QValidator.html): "any string that is a plausible intermediate state during entry of an `Acceptable` string is `Intermediate`."

Answer (score 1):

Came up with the following approach for replacing blanks, based on MadeOfAirs answer. It creates a new validator for each widget, though.

```
class QLineEditValidator(QValidator):

    @classmethod
    def connect(cls, line_edit, fixup=lambda s: s, validate=None, **kwargs):
        line_edit.setValidator(cls(line_edit, fixup=fixup, validate=validate, **kwargs))

    def __init__(self, line_edit, fixup=lambda s: s, validate=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.line_edit, self._fixup, self._validate = line_edit, fixup, \
            (lambda s, p: fixup(s) == s) if validate is None else validate

    def validate(self, s, p):
        if self.line_edit.hasFocus():
            return QValidator.Acceptable
        return QValidator.Acceptable if self._validate(s, p) else QValidator.Invalid

    def fixup(self, s):
        self.line_edit.setText(self._fixup(s))

text = QLineEdit()
QLineEditValidator.connect(text, fixup=lambda s: s.replace(' ', '_'))
QLineEditValidator.connect(text, fixup=lambda s: s.replace(' ', '_'), 
    validate=lambda s, p: not ' ' in s)
```